# Algorithm to find the next number in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, numbers, sequence

Ever since I started programming this has been something I have been curious about. But seems too complicated for me to even attempt.

I'd love to see a solution.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5    // returns 6 (n + 1)
10, 20, 30, 40, 50   //returns 60 (n + 10)
10, 17, 31, 59, 115  //returns 227 ((n * 2) - 3)
```

Comment: Well the first two are easy but how to generalize ?

Comment: I think that the second row returns 60...

Comment: Yeah, thanks Maurizio. Missed that. :p

Comment: Regarding your 3rd example, see this: http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/index.html?q=10%2C+17%2C+31%2C+59%2C+115&language=english&go=Search

Comment: There are infinitely-many functions; who's to say that the next number is really 6?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you want to do is called *polynomial interpolation*. There are many methods (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation ), but you have to have an upper bound U on the degree of the polynomial and at least U + 1 values.

If you have sequential values, then there is a simple algorithm.

Given a sequence x1, x2, x3, ..., let Delta(x) be the sequence of differences x2 - x1, x3 - x2, x4 - x3, ... . If you have consecutive values of a degree n polynomial, then the nth iterate of Delta is a constant sequence.

For example, the polynomial n^3:

```
1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, ...
7, 19, 37, 61, 91, ...
12, 18, 24, 30, ...
6, 6, 6, ...
```

To get the next value, fill in another 6 and then work backward.

```
6, 6, 6, 6 = 6, ...
12, 18, 24, 30, 36 = 30 + 6, ...
7, 19, 37, 61, 91, 127 = 91 + 36, ...
1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343 = 216 + 127, ...
```

The restriction on the number of values above ensures that your sequence never becomes empty while performing the differences.

Comment: Ya, this is really the basis of the Babbage difference engine.  Figure out that the Nth derivative is a constant, and simply addition give you the next number.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to disappoint, but this isn't quite possible (in general), as there are an infinite number of sequences for any given `k` values.  Maybe with certain constraints..

You can take a look at this [Everything2](http://everything2.com/title/How+to+solve+any+number+sequence+puzzle) post, which points to [Lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Yes there may well be lots of possibilities however couldn't you just find one that works for the given array and use that? It doesn't necessarily need to cover every single possibility. Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem is the next number can be literally anything, and you can figure out a pattern/polynomial to fit that new pattern.  For example, there's a pattern that fits, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, but also 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5..

Comment: But I mean just find a formula to fit those 5 numbers then use that to  get the 6th.

Comment: That said, the statement "with certain constraints" is not a throwaway, if you have certain constraints (let's say you restrict them to a polynomial order 2, `ax^2 + bx + c`) you might be able to come up with something.  But in general, it is not.

Comment: You can find an infinite number of formulas that fit the 5 numbers to get a 6th.

Comment: @Larry, I think it's safe to assume in this case, that the numbers are following a pattern that is represented in the given data. Otherwise the question is meaningless.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5        // returns 0   (n % 6)

Comment: In any case, take a look at the set of links - the discussion is probably what you are expecting.

Comment: On a side note, a number of years ago, I wrote one of those fun "sequences" online test to see how much of a "math geek" you are, with the understanding of what I claimed above as the disclaimer.  I still get angry emails to this day about how useless it is.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

Formally there is no unique next value to a partial sequence. The problem as usually understood can be clearly stated as:

> Assume that the partial sequence exhibited is just sufficient to constrain some generating rule, deduce the simplest possible rule and exhibit the next value generated.

The problem turns on the meaning of "simplest", and is thus not really good for algorithmatic solutions. It can be done if you confine the problem to a certain class of functional forms for the generating rule, but the details depend on what forms you are willing to accept.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) has pages and pages of real practical algorithms to do this kind of stuff. It's well worth the read!

The first two cases are easy:

```
>>> seq1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> seq2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> def next(seq):
...   m = (seq[1] - seq[0])/(1-0)
...   b = seq[0] - m * 0
...   return m*len(seq) + b
>>> next(seq1)
6
>>> next(seq2)
60
```

The third case would require solving for a non-linear function.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea and sequence one and two would seem to me that this is possible, but then again you cannot generalize as the sequence could totally go off base.  The answer is probably that you cannot generalize, what you can do is write an algorithm to perform a specific sequence knowing the (n+1) or (2n+2) etc...

One thing you may be able to do is take a difference between element i and element i+1 and element i+2.

for example, in your third example:

```
10 17 31 59 115
```

Difference between 17 and 10 is 7, and the difference between 31 and 17 is 14, and the difference between 59 and 31 is 28, and the diffeerence between 115 and 59 is 56.

So you note that it becomes the element i+1 = i + (7*2^n).

So 17 = 10 + (7*2^0)

And 31 = 17 + (7*2^1)

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [**extrapolation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation). It will help you to find formulas to describe a given sequence.

I am sorry, I can't tell you much more, since my mathematic education happened quite a while ago. But you should find more informations in good books.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of number series are often part of "intelligence tests", which leads me to think in the terms of such an algorithm being something passing (at least part of) a [Turing Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test), which is something quite hard to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary function it can't be done, but for a linear function like in each of your examples it's simple enough.

You have `f(n+1) = a*f(n) + b`, and the problem amounts to finding `a` and `b`.

Given at least three terms of the sequence, you can do this (you need three because you have three unknowns -- the starting point, `a`, and `b`).  For instance, suppose you have `f(0)`, `f(1)` and `f(2)`.

We can solve the equations:

```
f(1) = a*f(0) + b
f(2) = a*f(1) + b
```

The solution for is:

```
a = (f(2)-f(1))/(f(1)-f(0))
b = f(1) - f(0)*(f(2)-f(1))/(f(1)-f(0))
```

(You'll want to separately solve the case where `f(0) = f(1)` to avoid division by zero.)

Once you have `a` and `b`, you can repeatedly apply the formula to your starting value to generate any term in the sequence.

One could also write a more general procedure that works when given *any* three points in the sequence (e.g. 4th, 7th, 23rd, or whatever) . . . this is just a simple example.

Again, though, we had to make some assumptions about what form our solution would have . . . in this case taking it to be linear as in your example.  One could take it to be a more general polynomial, for instance, but in that case you need more terms of the sequence to find the solution, depending on the degree of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

See also the chapter "To Seek Whence Comes a Sequence" from the book "Fluid concepts and creative analogies: computer models of the fundamental mechanisms of thought" by Douglas Hofstadter

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=218753.218755&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=80584820&CFTOKEN=18842417